# Add JavaScript to some domain?

Tags: javascript

I seem to recall that there is a Firefox or Chrome plugin that allows you to run JavaScript, based upon the domain name. I basically want to write code to modify one particular site.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[Greasemonkey](https://addons.mozilla.org/en-US/firefox/addon/greasemonkey/) and [user scripts](http://lifehacker.com/5461675/chrome-4-supports-greasemonkey-userscripts-without-an-extension)

Comment: +1 greasemonkey is the right tool for that job.